# Fingerprint functions for set equality checks?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, crc

Given I have two sets of objects $A =\{a, b, c\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c, a\}$

- Based on the set equality, I want the fingerprint of these sets to be the same $F(A) = F(B)$.
- Additionally I want to be able merge fingerprints in order to calculate the fingerprint of the union. $F(\{a,b\} \cup \{c,a\}) = Merge(F(\{a,b\}), F(\{c,a\}))$

I think this resembles linear fingerprint functions (such as CRC) as in:

$CRC(x \oplus y \oplus z) = CRC(x) \oplus CRC(y)\oplus CRC(z)$

A similar concept exists in cryptography, called homomorphic hash functions:

$H(\{a\}) \oplus H(\{b\}) = H(\{a, b\})$

However, those can't be used for this purpose, as they won't handle duplications. Can you think of any fingerprint function that the probability of collision could be calculated?

*Note: Intuitively, a reasonable trade-off could be letting the fingerprint grow (ideally sublinearly) as the cardinality grows.*

Comment: This question has been addressed on cstheory https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3390/43

Comment: I think the accepted answer for that works for a multiset

Answer (score 1):

A [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) has this property.  Use the Bloom filter itself as the fingerprint.  The merge operation [can be implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Interesting_properties) as bitwise OR.

---

For multisets, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54544/351 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11420/351.

Comment: I know the false positive rate could be calculated. But couldn’t figure out what would the probability of collision be for the entire bloom filter.

Comment: @zetaprime, sorry, I don't know what "probability of collision" refers to.

Comment: What I mean is the false positive rate of the equality of the fingerprints in this case.

Comment: @zetaprime, you should be able to calculate that for Bloom filters, and the result should apply to the results of the merge as well.  The probability is likely to depend on the size of the sets.