# Is there a distributed streaming algorithm to verify set cover?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, sets, streaming-algorithm

I have $k$ sets of similar sizes, that cover a universe $U$.

e.g. for $k=3$ and $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$:

$S_0 = \{1, 2, 4\}$

$S_1 = \{2, 3, 4\}$

$S_2 = \{4, 5, 6\}$

I have another larger set $C$ **guaranteed** to be subset of $U$.

$C \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{k} s_{i}$.

e.g. $C = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

I want to be able to verify whether $C$ and $U$ are equal or not.

Is there a distributed streaming algorithm that has a minimal space complexity with an acceptable false positive rate?

- Sets $S_i$ are distributed on independent nodes, they need to be processed independently.
- $C$ is local.

An ideal solution would process the subsets $S_0,S_1, .. S_k$ in a single pass and create a sketch or a summary structure which then could be combined to verify against $C$. $C$ can be processed in multiple passes.

**My thoughts towards a solution:**

I thought of using an $n$-bit hashing algorithm. After hashing every element I could mark them on a bitset of size $2^n$. OR'ing these bitsets would give me the bitset of their union. Therefore I can calculate these bitsets once per $S_i$, collect these bitsets, OR them to compare against the bitset of $C$.

I'm not sure if there's a better solution than this (or even if this is a good solution or not). I can't really tell what would the false positive rate be, but I can tell it will be smaller as $n$ grows (at the exponential expense of bitset space).

**Note:**
I had asked a similar question earlier: [Fingerprint functions for set equality checks?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148798/fingerprint-functions-for-set-equality-checks). I realized later on, the actual problem I'm trying to solve is the special case of that problem. Here the larger set $C$ is guaranteed to be a subset of the union of all smaller sets $S_0, S_1, .. S_k$.

Comment: This is not a streaming algorithm, but uses a gossip model, so it may be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10706 . The main idea is to rephrase the problem as an LP-type problem, and use a distributed version of [Clarksons algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP-type_problem#Clarkson) (which is a Las Vegas algorithm).